# How to make two parallel functions talk to each other?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, telegram-bot

I want to stop a python script from running, using a Telegram Bot. I set up a "telegram read" function and a "stop" function ran in parallel via multiprocessing. I need the "stop" function to read the list of messages that the "telegram read" function updates but am not sure how to do that. I know there are better methods to implement this without using multiprocessing but I would like to learn how to do it that way for future usage.

This is a simplification of the code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import time

messages = []


def telegram_read():
    client = TelegramClient('anon', API_ID, API_HASH)

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=BOT_NAME))
    async def my_event_handler(event):
        messages.append(event.raw_text)

    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()


def check():
    while True:
        if 'STOP' in messages:
            stop_script()
            return
        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=telegram_read)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=check)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

I'm really new to python (I've been coding for 1 month) so sorry for the mistakes. Thank you!

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do that. Update your `check()` method like the following, it will extract and check in the updated messages to see if `STOP` is in there. If found then it will set the `stop_flag` to `True` and break out of the loop:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import time

def telegram_read(api_id, api_hash, bot_name, messages_queue, stop_flag):
    client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=bot_name))
    async def my_event_handler(event):
        message_text = event.raw_text
        messages_queue.put(message_text)

    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()
    stop_flag.put(True)  # Signal to stop the check process


def check(messages_queue, stop_flag):
    while True:
        if not messages_queue.empty():
            message = messages_queue.get()
            print(f"Received message: {message}")

            if 'STOP' in message:
                print("Stopping...")
                stop_flag.put(True)
                break

        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    messages_queue = Queue()
    stop_flag = Queue()

    p1 = Process(target=telegram_read, args=(api_id, api_hash, bot_name,
                 messages_queue, stop_flag))
    p2 = Process(target=check, args=(messages_queue, stop_flag))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Also, put stop-flag in your `telegram_read()` too to avoid threading error